# How to extract the text part of hastags using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, hashtag, tweets

I am trying to scrape some data from twitter to perform sentiments analysis, I want to be able to get the username, tweets, number of likes, number of retweets, location, date and hashtag.
Every other one works for me except the hashtag. I am getting both the text and indices, however, I only want the text. Help me, please ;(
Below is the code for that part;

```
data = []

for tweet in tweets:
    data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text, tweet.favorite_count, 
                 tweet.retweet_count, tweet.user.location, tweet.created_at, tweet.entities['hashtags']])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Username', 'Tweet', 'No. of Likes', 'No. of Retweets', 'Location', 'Date', 'Hashtag'])
print(df)
```

I tried tweets.entities['hashtags'] and I expected to get only the hashtags.
I even tried tweets['hashtags'][1][1]['text'] since I saw it somewhere but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

to get hashtags as a list use:

```
list(map(lambda a:a['text'],tweet.entities['hashtags']))
```